# Loss of .eps file quality after using scp to transfer from remote server

Tags: scp, images, file-transfer

When I scp (secure copy protocol) a .eps image file (generated using IDL) from a remote server to my desktop, the image seems to be of a lowered resolution and "choppy". Strangely, when I transfer from one remote server to another I do not have this problem. How can I maintain image quality while transferring such files to my desktop?

Comment: Are you sure you were viewing the EPS file and not some other file with a different extension which whatever viewing application you used read instead?

Comment: I've used evince on the remote server and the desktop. And the file is eps.

Answer (score 3):

The `scp` protocol provides a byte-identical copy service. You can verify that after doing an `scp`, the same file exists on both the source and the destination (for example, you could look at the file size and the result of `md5sum`). If the files are indeed identical, then your lowered resolution has a different cause, not `scp`.